# Using Rmarkdown for automated reports in a generated folder structure

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

It seems that R Markdown wasn't intended for being "fed" any data from a script that calls it. I have an automated script that creates a folder tree based on the section, employee, and date. As the script creates outputs, it places them in this folder structure.  Then I call Rmarkdown to render a pdf of the results. And lastly the script emails the pdf off.

I can make this work in Rstudio, but not through command line. (The script is called by a monitoring script automatically as needed, so it won't be running in Rstudio.)

````
home_dir <- "/home/pc/program"
runpath <- "/home/pc/program/section/employee/2019-02-05"
run <- 1

#R script
save.image()
rmarkdown::render(paste0(home_dir,"/report_1.Rmd"),
                output_file =  paste0("Run_",run,"_","Report.pdf"), 
                output_dir = runpath)



#report_1.Rmd
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
load("/.RData")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```
````

This works in RStudio by saving the workspace, and then loading it into the RMarkdown environment so all of my data can be placed in the report template.

BUT, when you run this in command line, it is unable to find the .RData file. RMarkdown only knows to search in the directory it is housed in. (/home/pc/program in this case)

Is there anyway to pass the environment or directory structure to the RMarkdown file when it is called from within an R sript?

Comment: Do you want to load the rendered pdf?

Comment: `save.image()` will save your environment at the current working directory of the calling R session. If this location is fixed, you could specify the full path to the image at that location in the R Markdown file (e.g., `load("path/to/wd/.RData")`, no?